# User account database in cansecurity

Tags: node.js, security, express

I'm creating some toy applications and i need SSO and API authorization for multiple RESTful node.js/ Express applications.
I discovered [cansecurity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cansecurity) can do the job.

But i don't understand where does the user account information reside. From the github [example](https://github.com/deitch/cansecurity/blob/master/example/example.js), it looks like each toy application should have copies of user account stored and also do the validation.

I would like to understand where does the user account database fit in cansecurity.

Answer (score 0):

Cansecurity does not accept a datastore of user credentials for authentication and authorization. It takes a validation callback function during initialization which gets called for every endpoint request.

It is left to the developer to authenticate the user in the validate callback from cansecurity. This callback shares another callback that takes a user object with properties for authorization. The rules for authorization can be setup in Cansecurity.

Finally, Cansecurity is just a middleware and it is left to the application to maintain its databases.